# AWS CDK Events Add Target with Input Template

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am creating an event in AWS that when a file is dropped into S3, this rule is triggered and starts a step function (SfnStateMachine)

I have some cdk code (node.js) where I add the `SfnStateMachine` as a target of that rule.

I want to take the payload of the S3 event and use `inputPathsMap` to map to a readable format, then I can use the `inputTemplate` to set the payload that will be sent to the Step Function.

```
 const inputTemplate = {
    Payload: {
      TriggerType: "<detailType>",
      TriggerReason: "<reason>",
      Version: "<versionId>"
    },
  }


rule.addTarget(new events_targets.SfnStateMachine(mystateMachine.stateMachine, {
  input: events.RuleTargetInput.fromObject({ 
    inputPathsMap: {
      detailType: "$.detail-type", 
      reason:"$.detail.reason",
      versionId:"$.detail.object.version-id"
    },
    inputTemplate: JSON.stringify(inputTemplate) }),
  role,
}))
```

When I use this, it is literally sending the value within `withObject`

I have looked at the docs and the `RuleTargetInput.bind()` seems like what I want to use, but I can't see an example of how its used. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-events.RuleTargetInput.html

I wanted to do something like

```
rule.addTarget(new events_targets.SfnStateMachine(ddStateMachine.stateMachine, {
  input: events.RuleTargetInput.bind(),
  role,
}))
```

but I don't know where to set the `inputTemplate` or the `inputPathsMap` because they are the return type rather than the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [EventField](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.EventField.html) helpers to define `input`, which defines the Step Function payload:

```js
rule.addTarget(
  new events_targets.SfnStateMachine(ddStateMachine.stateMachine, {
    input: events.RuleTargetInput.fromObject({
      detailType: events.EventField.detailType,
      reason: events.EventField.fromPath("$.detail.reason"),
      versionId: events.EventField.fromPath("$.detail.object.version-id"),
    }),
    role,
  })
);
```

Building the `InputPathMap` and `InputTemplate` is a job for the CDK.  The event target construct's synthesized output in the `Rule > Targets` resource definition is:

```json
"InputTransformer": {
  "InputPathsMap": {
    "detail-type": "$.detail-type",
    "detail-reason": "$.detail.reason",
    "detail-object-version-id": "$.detail.object.version-id"
  },
  "InputTemplate": "{\"detailType\":<detail-type>,\"reason\":<detail-reason>,\"versionId\":<detail-object-version-id>"
```

Comment: So whatever payload I want to send to my Step function when triggered by this event, I would just set in the events.ruleTargetInput.fromObject object?

Comment: @bananabreadbob Yes, exactly.

Comment: this helped me, I didn't grasp that the InputPathsMap and InputTemplate were generated and used by the cdk and weren't really required by me as it only introduced an extra step anyway. Thank you